# Unable to parse date using LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, datetimeformatter

I am trying to parse a date string using DateTimeFormatter. I am receiving the below exception:

Wrong date format 10.10.2020 12:00:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10.10.2020 12:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2

```
 String date="10.10.2020 12:00:00";
  
 String dateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
 String exportTimeZone = "UTC";

 DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);

 LocalDateTime impDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(StringUtils.trim(date), format);
 ZonedDateTime dateInUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(impDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(exportTimeZone)).toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
 return format.format(dateInUtc);
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Your date String doesn't match is "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", it is either "MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss" or "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: "10.10.2020 12:00:00" is _definitely_ not in the format you specified, which is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s read the message:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10.10.2020 12:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2

Indices are 0-based, so index 2 in `10.10.2020 12:00:00` is where the first dot (period, point) is. So Java is unable to parse that dot. To find out why, let’s look at the corresponding place in the format pattern string

```
String dateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
```

So the month, 10, has been successfully parsed and next the formatter expects — a slash. The discrepancy between slash and dot explains the exception.

A further tip: When it gets non-trivial to get the format pattern string for parsing right, try formatting a known date first:

```
    System.out.println("To be parsed: " + date);
    LocalDateTime knownDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER, 10, 12, 0);
    System.out.println("Formatted:    " + knownDateTime.format(format));
```

Output in this case:

> ```
> To be parsed: 10.10.2020 12:00:00
> Formatted:    10/10/2020 12:00:00 PM
> ```

This way of printing it makes it easier to spot the differences between what we’ve got and what the formatter will expect for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `/` instead of `.` in the format. Also, when you are using `HH`, it means it is 24-hour format, not `am/pm` and therefore you shouldn't use `a` with `HH` in the format. Moreover, your date-time string does not have `am/pm` in it, so using `a` in the format will anyway cause an error.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTime = "10.10.2020 12:00:00";

        // Define the format
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        // Parse date-time as using the defined format
        LocalDateTime impDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, format);

        // Get date-time at UTC
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeInUtc = impDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        // Display
        System.out.println(dateTimeInUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-10T12:00Z[Etc/UTC]
```